# Continuous collaborative filtering using Mahout

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am in the process of evaluating Mahout as a collaborative-filtering-recommendation engine. So far it looks great.
We have almost 20M boolean recommendations from 12M different users. 
According to [Mahout's wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommender-first-timer-faq.html) and a few threads by [Sean Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64174/sean-owen), one machine should sufficient in this case. Because of that I decided to go with MySql as the data-model and skip the overhead of using Hadoop for now.

One thing eludes me though, what are the best practices for continuously updating the recommendations without reading the whole data from scratch? We have tens-of-thousands of new recommendations every day. While I do not expect it to be processed at real-time, I would like to have it processed every 15 minutes or so.

Please elaborate on the approaches for both a Mysql-based and Hadoop-based deployment.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any database is too slow to query in real-time, so any approach involves caching the data set in memory, which is what I assume you're already doing with `ReloadFromJDBCDataModel`. Just use `refresh()` to have it re-load at whatever interval you like. It should do so in the background. The catch is that it will need a lot of memory to load the new model while serving from the old one. You could roll your own solutions that, say, reload a user at a time.

There's no such thing as real-time updates on Hadoop. Your best bet there in general is to use Hadoop for full and proper batch computation of results, and then tweak them at run-time (imperfectly) based on new data in the app that is holding and serving recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I'm a little bit puzzled about how Hadoop fits in the overall picture. As far as I understand, it is used to pre-compute the similarities thus leaving the application itself only to do the matching according to the chosen recommender. Is that truly the case?

Comment: Hadoop doesn't necessarily have to be a part of this. I would not use Hadoop unless you are forced to by issues of scale. Yes, you could use it for part of the process, computing similarities offline.

Comment: Sean, what did you mean with "reload a user at a time"? I'm using ReloadFromJDBCDataModel but when I call reload() the entire dataset is reloaded. I understand that reloading just the user for which we are asking recommendations would make sense, how could I achieve that?

Comment: I mean that it's conceivable to write your own implementation that loads the latest data for one user and updates that in memory, and so on for each user. It requires less memory. but the current implementation doesn't work this way.